# Can I find out what exactly is "android system" traffic?

Tags: data-monitoring

I'm using Android 4.4.4 CyanogenMOD 12. My traffic is dominated by "android-system" - about half of my data usage is caused by "it" and I have no idea why it transfers data. backup (backup & restore) is turned off. I dont use any Google Service besides the play store (and very seldomly youtube).
All the "android system"-traffic is background-trafic.

Is there any chance (tool/app/whatever) to find out what exactly the cause for the "android system" traffic is?

PS: 
- I use AFWall+ and in 3G even most of the system apps are blocked.
- I do not have the "Photos" app

Comment: Could it be the [account synchronisation](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2840875?hl=en)?

Comment: android system is the core-system it's an API that can be accesed by any third party app on the phone that have the right permissions so it's gonna be difficult to find what is using that data exactly  try disabling  background-trafic under settings > more > data usage  then option and check the "Restrict background data" checkbox

Comment: It is too much data in order to be account sync I think - and I disabled all syncing i know.
I'll try the restrict background data idea.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. I used ARM version of `tcpdump` command. You must copy that command by hand in `/system/xbin/`. In shell you ran:

```
tcpdump -i rmnet0 -w /sdcard2/tcpdump.pcap
```

After some time kill that tcpdump command and copy file tcpdump.pcap to PC. Then use Wireshark to load tcpdump.pcap file to investigate network traffic.

Comment: well, this is all traffic caused by the system, isn't it?
It would be quite hard to filter...

Comment: yes, it is. but this is some info than nothing